# Finding TFS Express Version from database backups

Tags: tfs

One of our server crashed running TFS express for personal projects. We do have tfs database backups on network location but not sure what version it was.
Is there any possible way to identify tfs version from database backups ?

Comment: What's the meaning of version in your question, did you mean the backup version of database?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT No, the version of tfs software that was installed on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the extended property `TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION` of any collection database (e.g. **Tfs_DefaultCollection**) using SQL Management Studio; then lookup in [What version of Team Foundation Server do I have?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have.aspx)

`TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION` is a bit easier to read if you are familiar with internal Visual Studio versions.

Comment: Found it, thanks : Microsoft Team Foundation Server Dev12 Update 4

Comment: This really helped me find the correct version to install after only having the db to restore.

Answer (score -1):

TFS isn't installed client-side. On the client you use **Team Explorer**, which is part of **Visual Studio**. So the only version on the client-side that is with the Visual Studio version which you get from Help->About. This may give what you want.

The version is stored with the ***file version*** of the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll` file. Not sure if this is contained in backuplogs. You can also double check it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question -- the question indicated that TFS was offline and they only had database backups available.